# Selecting translation service in Opera

Tags: opera

How can I select a different translation service in Opera? When you select a portion of text and right-click it you have the option to translate the text. This defaults to using the Bing service but I want to use Google Translate. Is it possible to switch to Google Translate and how do I do that?

I have Opera 12.

Comment: Would also be nice to actually have options on the menu items, and not just the predefined choices.

Comment: @Emil Vikström: You should accept [**nixda**'s answer](http://superuser.com/a/462115/62130), because that's the working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 options for you:

1. Use an addon like [Xtranslate](https://addons.opera.com/de/extensions/details/xtranslate/)
   It lets you choose between Google and Bing translation service and translates selected text instantly
2. Modify the Opera context menu and add a "translate" option

   - Duplicate your `standard_menu.ini` and copy it over to `..\opera\profile\menu`
   - Delete all sections except the header lines, [Version], [Info] and [Translate menu]
   - Replace or add to your [Translate menu] section these lines

     ```
     [Translate menu]
     Item, Google | "translate into german" = Copy & Go to page, "http://translate.google.com/?text=#auto|de|%c"
     Item, Google | "translate into english" = Copy & Go to page, "http://translate.google.com/?text=#auto|en|%c"
     ```

   These are two only examples. You can modify it to your own desired language.

Comment: +1: that's correct! And if you want to open the translation on a new tab, you should just change `Copy & Go to page` to `Copy & New Page & Go to page`.